# Selecting multiple excel files in different folders and comparing them with pandas

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, glob

I am trying to compare multiple excel files with pandas and glob, but i am getting the folowing output from my code:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []

This is my code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
path = 'S:\data\**\C_76_00_a?.xlsx'
for f in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True, skiprows=10, usecols=4)
    cdf = pd.concat(df.values(), axis=1) 
    all_data = all_data.append(cdf,ignore_index=True)
print(all_data)
```

I am using jupyter notebook and the folder structure is \2021\12\2021-30-12\ and the file name containg "C_76_00_a" +"something unknown +".xlsx"

Below is a screenshot of the type of document i am trying to compare

[image]

Comment: Try to use `usecols = "D"`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same output, what happens when I set usecols = "D"